# Join two tables without relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to `JOIN` two tables without relationship. Both tables have a different RowCount and DataType... I don't want to repeat any rows if one table has less rows than the other

```
TableA
A
B
C
```

```
TableB
4
2
```

Desired result:

```
TableA | TableB
A      |     4
B      |     2
C      |
```

Comment: What is your logic for 'assigning' `4` to `A`, why not to `B` or `C`?

Comment: There is no order in your tables unless you tell us a column used for ordering.  What is the logic by which 4 comes before 2 in the second table?

Comment: 1. Edit your question to tell us what reference you are learning from, this is absolutely basic. 2. You are unclear. Use enough sentences and words to say what you mean. 3. Lately google translate has some ai quantum improvements, try that with simple straighforward clear input. 4. Your example has a non-relation (non-table), please correct it. 5. We can join any tables, we don't need a "relationship" (FK). *Tables* represent business relation(ship)s/associations. 6 Tables have no order. SQL "result sets" have order. If your result involves order, explain.

Comment: If you are pasting two tables side by side, that is a faq. Google various ways to describe it. Although the answer below is duplicating those answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `union all` or by using `row_number()`:

```
select col1, col2
from (select a.col1, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a full outer join
     (select b.col2, row_number() over (order by col2) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

Comment: select c.id,c.category,b.id ,b.brand_name from (select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) rn,id,category FROM tbl_category order by category) c full outer join (select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) rn, id, brand_name FROM tbl_brand order by brand_name ) b on c.rn =b.rn .-----------------------------------------------------------‌​------ now this is my query but one proble facein in b table column null values added randomly ... i want empty values will show at the end

Comment: @user2638158 . . . This should show all the values in the two columns, up to the longer table.

Answer (score -1):

easiest way is assigning row number to both table A & B

```
select a.items, 
       b.items
from (select rn=row_number()  over (order by (select 0)) ,items from TableA ) a
full outer join (select rn=row_number()  
over (order by (select 0)) ,items from TableB  ) b 
on a.rn =b.rn
```

Comment: select c.id,c.category,b.id ,b.brand_name
from (select row_number()  over (order by (select 0)) rn,id,category FROM tbl_category order by category) c
full outer join (select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) rn, id, brand_name  FROM tbl_brand order by brand_name  ) b 
on c.rn =b.rn   .-----------------------------------------------------------------  now this is my query but one proble facein in b table column null values added randomly ... i want empty values will show at the end

Comment: `rn=row_number()` is invalid SQL